# method returns the number of odd numbers in the array of integers

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I get an error message saying:

> This method must return a result of type int.

My code:

```
public int countOdds (int[] values) {
  int countOdd =0;
  for (int i=0; i<values.length; i++) {
    if (values[i] %2 != 0) {
      countOdd++;
      return countOdd;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Compiler thinks that the method may not return anything at all:

```
public int countOdds (int[] values) {
  int countOdd =0;
  for (int i=0; i<values.length; i++) {
    if (values[i] %2 != 0){
      countOdd++;
      return countOdd;
    }
  }
  // what if this line is reached?
}
```

Suppose you run it with `values.length = 0`. What will the method return?

Your `return` statement should be in a different place in code

Comment: Or if all items in `values` are even?

Answer (score 5):

The following line

```
return countOdd;
```

should be outside of your for-loop.

Otherwise, you'll either return 1 when you reach the first odd, or you won't reach a return statement at all if there are no odds.

```
public int countOdds (int[] values) {
  int countOdd =0;
  for (int i=0; i<values.length; i++) {
    if (values[i] %2 != 0) {
      countOdd++;
    }
  }
  return countOdd;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the `values` array has no odd numbers in it, then your function exits without returning an `int`.  As noted in a previous answer, move the `return` statement out of the loop.

Also, because the value of `values[i]%2` is 0 for even numbers and 1 for odd numbers, the number of odd numbers is equal to the sum over `i` of `values[i]%2`, allowing you to significantly shorten the code:

```
public int countOdds (int[] values) {
  int i, count=0;
  for (i=0; i<values.length; ++i) {
    count += values[i]%2;
  }
  return count;
}
```

An alternative version uses bitwise AND:

```
 public int countOdds (int[] values) {
  int i, count=0;
  for (i=0; i<values.length; ++i) {
    count += values[i] & 1;
  }
  return count;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Supposing the if-statement never returns true, will the method return anything? No, it won't, so you need to include a return statement that will execute in the event the if-statement never runs.

```
  public int countOdds (int[] values) {
  int countOdd =0;
  for (int i=0; i<values.length; i++) {
    if (values[i] %2 != 0) {
      countOdd++;
    }
  }
  return countOdd;
}
```

Comment: No reason include the magic number `0`; it's just a matter of moving  the variable down to return instead of a number.

Comment: This method returns zero or one only. -1